# Spring MVC - how are autowired resources shared by threads

Tags: spring-mvc

I wrote a small spring-mvc app to better understand how autowired resources are shared between different user request threads.

**My controller:**

```
@Autowired
SharedResource sharedResource;

@RequestMapping(value = "/spring-sample/index",method= RequestMethod.GET)
public void index(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException, ServletException{

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    request.setAttribute("value", sharedResource.accessme());
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

**SharedResource.java:**

```
@Service
public class SharedResource {

private Integer i;

public SharedResource(){
    i=0;
}

public Integer accessme(){
    int i=0;

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SharedResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    ++i;
    return i;
}
```

}

the `index.jsp` just prints the returned integer.

I opened two browsers(ie, then chrome) and hit my app one after other.

This is how i walkedthrough the code.

1. Thread1(request from ie) calls `accessme`, sets the value of `i` to 0 and goes to sleep
2. Thread2(request from chrome) calls `accessme`, sets the value of `i` to 0 and goes to sleep
3. Thread1 awakes, increments the value of `i` to 1 and returns 1
4. Thread2 awakes, increments the value of `i` to 2 and returns 2

So, I expected ie to print `1` and chrome to print `2`

but ie printed `1` and then chrome printed `1`

how is this possible ?

Eventhough the threads share the same object and make a call to that object, it seems like each thread has its own copy of the method which share the object's instance variables but each operate in their own sandboxed environment. is this the expected behavior ?

Please let me know if I am horribly wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `i` again in the `accessme` method. This local variable overwrites the field.

If you want this to be multithread safe, you should an AtomicInteger: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Comment: The threads behave like each gets its own copy of the method though they share the object and instance variables. So if the methods don't access instance variables of its own, are they then safe from multithreaded issues ?

Comment: @PSathiya  yes if no instance valriables then no problem

Comment: does this mean, since the local variables are stored in a stack, each thread gets its own copy of the stack ?

Comment: yes @PSathiya they are not on heap so that one copy is shared by multiple threads and when multiple thread access the instance variables simultaneously then dirty data problem

Answer (score 0):

all the beans By default having `singleton scopes` in spring IOC container  so not thread safe
You have to use `@Scope={"prototype"}` to make it thread safe

```
@Autowired
@Scope={"prototype"}
SharedResource sharedResource;
```

now for each request a new instance of `SharedResource` will be avialable

Comment: You are right, but I don't this is what is requested. It would not print `1` and `2` in the different browsers by doing this.